# Plotting 2d histogram of data with very different ranges in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I try to plot a 2d histogram of data with very different ranges using the following code. However, because of the different data ranges, the x data overlaps like the following figure. Is there any solution that plots x and y data with the same axis length?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.clf()
x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=8873)
y = np.random.randint(low=100000,high=600000, size=8873)
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.imshow(... aspect='auto')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `imshow()` sets the aspect to `1` by default, changing it to `auto` should solve your problem. You can also calculate your own aspect based on extent to get for example a square image.

```py
aspect = (extent[1] - extent[0]) / (extent[3] - extent[2])
plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, origin='lower', aspect=aspect)
# plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, origin='lower', aspect='auto')
```

[image: imshow with custom aspect ratio]